# MvvmCross with SQLite extremely slow

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

This is an Android application using Xamarin.

I have a simple search screen where the users select to filter based on state, city, interstate, etc (1 or more options).  When state is changed, the other dropdowns change appropriately (based on what cities exist in that state, or interstates, etc).  It's taking 2 seconds or more every time I change the state dropdown to update the other dropdowns, and meanwhile the UI is not responsive.  I also notice the RaisePropertyChanged events don't actually occur until all code in the set method is completed.  How can I speed up things to give a better user experience?

Here is the SQL call that is slow.  I'm looking for a list of child objects based on a property of the parent.

```
        var parentIds = _connection.Table<Parent>().Where(x => x.State == state).Select(x => x.Id);
        return _connection.Table<Child>()
                          .Where(x => parentIds.Contains(x.ParentId))
                          .Select(x => x.ChildProperty)
                          .OrderBy(x => x)
                          .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the query to the following:

```
        var parentIds = _connection.Table<Parent>().Where(x => x.State == state).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        var children = _connection.Table<Child>().ToList();
        return
            children.Where(x => parentIds.Contains(x.ParentId))
                    .Select(x => x.ChildProperty)
                    .OrderBy(x => x)
                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: I am curious though why this query works so much better in SqlLite.  It's pretty much identical to the poor performing query except that I am calling .ToList() to force the objects to be loaded into memory before calling my Linq query.

Answer (score 2):

With all optimisations, "measure first, optimise second".

When you say something is extremely slow, identify what is. Is it the UI redraw? Is it one particular SQLite call? Is it one particular thread interaction.

Once you've identified what is slow, then there are techniques you can use:

- to put various slow things on background non-UI threads
- to virtualise memory loading (so you don't have to load the entirity of big lists)
- to cache data in-memory so you don't have to hit the database each time
- to add more indexing to a large database (or an in-memory store)

But all of these sort of ideas should come after measurement (in my opinion and experience) as otherwise you can easily end up optimising the wrong thing.

Comment: Good point.  The SQL call that is looking for a list of child items based on a property of the parent is the part that is slow.  Adding this code to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Your advice led to the solution.